# Leaflet Sidebar - How to get data based on the GeoJSON you clicked?

Tags: leaflet, jquery

I am having trouble getting my GeoJSON data to appear on my sidebar when I click on a marker?

As right now, I am able to click on a marker and make the sidebar appear, but without any information.

Below is the line of code I am using:

```
var aLayer = L.geoJson(GeoJSON, {      
    });

aLayer.on('click', function () {
        sidebar.toggle();
        $('Name').innerHTML = "Name: " + feature.properties.name;
    });
```

My real issue is that I can't figure out how to call the GeoJSON properties when I click on the marker. I am keeping getting this error when I check the console log: feature is not defined. I tried using the code that is provided in this page,[Leaflet Sidebar - set content depending on clicked GeoJSON feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201987/leaflet-sidebar-set-content-depending-on-clicked-geojson-feature), but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Which version of leaflet are you using and what's the problem with the code you are referencing.

Answer (score 1):

First, check you using the correct jquery selector, probably `$('#Name')` instead of `$('Name')`

Then use the parameter of the callback function to get the event, and check its properties. Probably something like this will work:

```
aLayer.on('click', function (e) {
  sidebar.toggle();
  var name = e.target.feature.properties.name
  $('#name').innerHTML = "Name: " + feature.properties.name;
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help, but I still could not get the information from the GeoJSON to appear on the sidebar. I changed the jquery selector to $('#Name') since I have Name as an id in my html. I am not sure if this information will help, but  I am using Leaflet Sidebar version one. I am trying to call my GeoJSON layer's feature.properties every time I click on the marker on my web map.

Comment: e.target doesn't have any properties under it.

Comment: I found the right path.. as of leaflet v.1.3.1 at least.. it's `e.layer.properties.name`

Comment: The `layer` property in an `object event` is deprecated for some events. http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#event-layer. `target` should be always present in a leaflet event and represents the object that fired the event.

Answer (score 1):

The correct path, at least as of leaflet v.1.3.1, is `e.layer.properties.name`.

```
aLayer.on('click', function (e) {
        sidebar.toggle();
        $('Name').innerHTML = "Name: " + e.layer.properties.name;
    });
```

Edit: Even I'm finding this stuff a bit unpredictable. The way I found out for this time was, by console.log'ing everything and exploring around in the console.

```
aLayer.on('click', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Then through exploring in the browser console (Ctrl+Shift+J) and trial and error, found my way to `e.layer.properties.name`. When I saw my other scripts again recently I found the path there was different! Perhaps it changes based on the nature of the layers.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `e.target`, `e.layer`, etc. stopped getting propagated by newer Leaflet.
`e.feature` still works in Leaflet 1.6.0:

```
feature.sidebar_content = content                                                                            
layer.on("click", function(e){                                                                                    
             sidebar.toggle();                                                                                            
             sidebar.setContent(e.target.feature.sidebar_content);                                                        
        });
```

I found this out by testing with `console.log(feature);`