# Leaflet Sidebar: Show specific sidebar content after clicking a location

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Similar question to [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201987/leaflet-sidebar-set-content-depending-on-clicked-geojson-feature) but I don't have enough knowledge to apply it to my case.

I have a Mapbox GL JS map (based on Leaflet) to which I added a Leaflet Sidebar V1. The sidebar content is made up of html using several levels of tabs like so:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openNation(event, 'NAT1')">Japan</button>
    </div>
    <div id="NAT1" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-auto"><div class="nav flex-column nav-pills">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#tabA1" id="listing-0" data-toggle="tab">Tokyo</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabA1"><p>Description of Tokyo.</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a whole structure of Nations and Cities. With the sidebar open, you first click on a country, which will display the list of its cities. You click on a city in the list, and the description will display, all of that in the sidebar.

What I want to do is to display the relevant description (and mark the relevant Nation and City as active) when you click on a city on the map.

I already have some functions associated with clicking on a city like so:

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
    // Query all the rendered points in the view
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['locations'] });
    if (features.length) {
        var clickedPoint = features[0];
        // Fly to the point
        flyToCity(clickedPoint);
          }
        });
```

Initially this code was taken from a tutorial which also included this:

```
       // 2. Close all other popups and display popup for clicked store
        createPopUp(clickedPoint);
        // 3. Highlight listing in sidebar (and remove highlight for all other listings)
            var activeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
            if (activeItem[0]) {
              activeItem[0].classList.remove('active');
            }
            // Find the index of the store.features that corresponds to the clickedPoint that fired the event listener
            var selectedFeature = clickedPoint.properties.name;

            for (var i = 0; i < cities.features.length; i++) {
              if (cities.features[i].properties.name === selectedFeature) {
                selectedFeatureIndex = i;
              }
            }
            // Select the correct list item using the found index and add the active class
            var listing = document.getElementById('listing-' + selectedFeatureIndex);
            listing.classList.add('active');
            // Shift view to selected item in sidebar
            listing.scrollIntoView(true);
```

I am not using the popup or the sidebar that this code is for since I've created my own Leaflet Sidebar V1, but I guess I could probably take inspiration from the code. However, I don't know enough to figure how to designate and set the leaflet sidebar content from a javascript function.

I'm attaching a screenshot for illustration purposes.

[image: How to make map click on city display the city's description]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest route is to have your Mapbox locations trigger a click event. Since that click will be targeted at a button in the sidebar, you get any 'onClick' function and 'data-toggle' functionality from the nav menu coming along.

The code below assumes the following which is not a Mapbox default:

1. the 'features' (aka list of cities) contains a 'nation' property;
2. because of the 'index' variable, the order in which the 'features' appear in the code must match the order in which the city tab IDs (nav-link) are numbered in the sidebar's nav menu (starting with 0, not 1). Or you can use the same method as for the 'nation' tabs, by adding a dedicated property to each 'feature', match them with the nav-link IDs and call the same function as with nations (selectedFeature1) instead of relying on an index.

.

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['locations'] });
    if (features.length) {
        var clickedPoint = features[0];
            var selectedFeature1 = clickedPoint.properties.nation;
            var sidebar = document.getElementById('NAT-' + selectedFeature1).click();               
            var selectedFeature2 = clickedPoint.properties.name;
            for (var i = 0; i < cities.features.length; i++) {
              if (cities.features[i].properties.name === selectedFeature2) {
                selectedFeature2Index = i;
              }
            }
            var sidebar = document.getElementById('listing-' + selectedFeature2Index).click();              
    }
    });
```

My question had been [closed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344881/leaflet-sidebar-show-specific-sidebar-content-after-clicking-a-location) whereas I think it was valid. It was about how to write a JavaScript function that simulates a click inside the Leaflet Sidebar by clicking on a choice of features included in a Mapbox map. The resulting code is listening to rendered points on the map and search for the right ID to click on in the sidebar.

I had thought this would be an easy one for people who are familiar with Mapbox's rendered location structure and some JavaScript basics. Ultimately I had to figure how JavaScript functions work from scratch to be able to write this, although I had hoped someone could give me a hand instead of closing my topic. My question and its context were sure complex, but they were perfectly clear. In the future I encourage the people who chose to comment negatively instead of helping me narrow down the issue and giving out some JS basics to be more constructive towards   less skilled/first-time coders who are still able to phrase a complex question. I am therefore posting this for other such people to use.